# How to check that tag exists in InfluxDB bucket?

Tags: influxdb

I am using bitcoin sample data, for example, and do the query in InfluxDB notebook UI like this:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"
schema.tagKeys(bucket: "bitcoin")
```

This works good. But then I want to find specific tag by its name.
I suppose following should work but doesn't:

```
schema.tagKeys(bucket: "bitcoin", predicate: (r) => r._value == "code")
```

I see error: `An internal error has occurred - check server logs`.
And the following string in logs:

```
ts=2023-06-05T08:50:06.835733Z lvl=warn msg="internal error not returned to client" log_id=0iB3ypUW000 handler=error_logger error="field values unsupported"
```

I'm not sure what does it mean.

I also tried to check if `_value` is valid property name and it is like so:

```
schema.tagKeys(bucket: "bitcoin", predicate: (r) => exists r._value)
```

above returns all 8 rows with tags names.

How can I find tag by its name? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way to filter it like this

```
schema.tagKeys(bucket: "bitcoin")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value == "code")
```